# CEN XFS: Opening Sensors and Indicator Module Causes Crash

Tags: c++, cen-xfs

I'm working with trying to get some information from the Sensors and Indicators module, but the program always crashes. When I debug step by step I get the result -48 (WFS_ERR_TIMEOUT) from WFSGetInfo() which means that it has timed out. The Sensor and Indicator registry key is present and the vendor DLL is also present. All the other modules are able to open just fine. Any idea what gives?

The SIU SPI version is 3.02 and I'm using SPI/XFS version 0x0B020003 and XFS SDK 3.20. Would this be one of the issues?

```
#include "XFS.h"
#include "XFSSIU.h"

int main()
{
    XFS xfs = XFS();

    xfs.start();

    HRESULT hResult = XFSObj.openSession("SIU");
    LPWFSRESULT lpResult = NULL;
    HRESULT open_result = NULL;
    open_result = WFSGetInfo(xfs.getServiceHandle(), WFS_INF_SIU_STATUS, NULL, 120000, &lpResult);
    std::cout << open_result << std::endl;
    XFSObj.CloseSession();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @SuperG280 Hi, you helped me last time, would you be able to help me figure what the issue could be?

Comment: All is possible with an error like this. It seems there is a problem with the SPI, configuration, installation, etc... Try to pass WFS_INDEFINITE_WAIT as timeout to test if it's needed more time to finish. I don't know.  Version is not the problem if you control the open result (open returns version error if the version you are asking is not valid). Any way, WFSGetInfo returns error if open is not ok.... So, I don't know... Try to find the vendor log file, check windows events...